# How to close socket when MaxUploadSizeExceededException occur?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing upload system of image. I set maxUploadSize, using CommonsMultipartResolver. When i try to upload over max size image file, MaxUploadSizeExccededException occur. but all of image file is sent, although it has over 1G byte.

how to close socket? I want close socket when this exception occur.

thanks you.

#### controller.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" >
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100" />
</bean>
```

#### controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="upload/", method={RequestMethod.POST})
public void uploadImage( ThumbnailRequestParams thumbnailRequestParams
                          , HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{   
        uploadImage(thumbnailRequestParams, response);
}
```

#### form.html

```
<form action="upload/" method="post" NAME="testForm" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/><br/>
    idName : <input type="text" id="idName" name="idName"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not throw an `IOException` but catch the `MaxUploadSizeExceededExeception`. In the catch block you can then close the socket.

Comment: Where can I catch MaxUploladSizeExceededException? I had read source code of http of tomcat and found out "endRequest function" that read all of stream of reqeust buffer. can i close this socket handled by tomcat?

Comment: How can I close the socket on server-side? Do you mean closing the ServletInputStream in the catch block? I can't believe that this prevents the client from further uploading. I think you have to send a message on a _second channel_ to the client and then stop the upload on client side. For example, you can use the same connection for monitoring upload progress for this purpose.

Comment: Actually, closing the InputStream and the underlying socket will terminate the connection, which will in turn abruptly send a connection reset signal to the client.  The client will not continue uploading, nor will the server continue accepting data.